# Map dev notation to logical volume name

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

I need to figure out what dm-2 or dm-0, etc. is (this notation is found in dmesg notices, sysstat reports, etc.) and lsblk is not installed
I find lvdisplay output a little bit confusing.

Can someone please help with simple script to identify which dm device maps to which LVM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple one liner for this purpose:

`lvdisplay|awk '/LV Name/{n=$3} /Block device/{d=$3; sub(".*:","dm-",d); print d,n;}'`

The output of above command should be like:

```
# lvdisplay|awk '/LV Name/{n=$3} /Block device/{d=$3; sub(".*:","dm-",d); print d,n;}'

dm-0 swap00
dm-1 tmp00
dm-2 root00
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The solution worked like a charm.